Datatype double declaration
I had a problem where, my answers were completely similar to the ones on the online judge, but they were deemed wrong.
I fixed it after a lot of tinkering, but I dont understand what is going on. Please explain what is going wrong.
This was my first program that gave the exact answers as the sample, but the onlinejudge said that it was wrong.

#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    double score,div,prob,coin=0.5;
    int n,k;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    
    div= 1.0/n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    
            score =i;
            
            coin=1;
            while(score<k){
                score*=2;
                coin*=0.5;

            }
            prob= prob+(coin * div);
        }
    
    printf("%.12lf",prob);
            
}

The onlinejudge says that this is correct:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    double score,div,prob=0.0,coin=0.5;
    int n,k;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    
    div= 1.0/n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    
            score =i;
            
            coin=1;
            while(score<k){
                score*=2;
                coin*=0.5;

            }
            prob= prob+(coin * div);
        }
    
    printf("%.12lf",prob);
            
}
    
    


I only changed the
double prob;

to
double prob=0.0;

Why is the first one wrong?

In the first program you only initialize coin. The prob variable will have an indeterminate value (treat it as garbage). So when you do the very first prob+(coin * div) the result will likely be wrong, and then get just worse.

Please check out the compiler warnings for the code. You have to initialize local (auto) variables yourself, explicitly.

@WeatherVane the compiler gave no warnings

Then you need to enable more warnings. And treat them as errors that must be fixed. If you use GCC or Clang, I recommend at least -Wall -Wextra -Werror.

Do you mean the online judge gave no warnings? You could compile and test the code on your own compiler or perhaps online at Compiler Explorer.

@Someprogrammerdude I did this  double score,div,coin,prob;   and it returns errors again

@WeatherVane Neither the judge, nor my personal compiler geany. (I am on linux)

@Someprogrammerdude alas this is not enough

I would not expect the judge to, because it is usually a programmer's challenge to submit correct code, not a tutor. They accept code that compiles. MSVC produces a warning with -W3 which is my typical use.

@Someprogrammerdude I used this gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o but still no errors

Somewhat to my surprise, I confirm that gcc does not warn me about the first code.  I suppose that is a gcc flaw, probably related to the fact that the first use of prob is in a statement that assigns to it (even though that statement also contains a read of prob).

Sometimes gcc needs -O or another optimization option to do enough analysis to generate warnings.

C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10) "If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate." C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined Behavior "The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)." So your failure to initialize prob invoked "Undefined Behavior" in your code. See: Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior

Geany is not a compiler, but an extended editor. Your compiler is GCC.
